# How to fix 2nd bootstrap modal loosing vertical scrollbars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

In bootstrap 3 - if you open a modal, then hide it before opening a second modal, the vertical scroll bars disappear on the second modal. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qfvnmbfd/

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#Modal1" class="btn btn-info">Open Modal 1</a>

<div id="Modal1" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="modal-label">Modal 1</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><a href="#" id="btn2" class="btn btn-info">Open Modal 2</a></p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!--modal-content-->
</div> <!--modal-dialog-->
```

```
<div id="Modal2" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 id="modal-label">Modal 2</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
            <p>Content.</p>
        </div>
    </div> <!--modal-content-->
</div> <!--modal-dialog-->
```

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#btn2", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //$('.modal.in').modal('hide')
            $('#Modal1').modal('hide');
            $('#Modal2').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by overriding the css:

```
.modal {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfvnmbfd/2/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of  this

```
 $('#Modal1').modal('hide');
 $('#Modal2').modal('show');
```

use

```
 $('#Modal1').modal("hide");
 $('#Modal2').modal("show");
```

That's it....

update

```
<div id="Modal2" class="modal fade" style="overflow:scroll">
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not fix the issue - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/efmnzvw3/

Comment: after adding this code to jsfiddle did you run that by pressing run button on title bar

Comment: @MWD please check now

Answer (score 0):

I have a css solution. use this css below.

```
#Modal2{
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```